# make entire image fill background with css

Tags: html, css, image, background

[image] Struggling to write CSS to format the image so that it covers the entire background of the page, as it doesn't seem to be able to do so below. It seems to be getting stuck up on the header and I am not sure how to correct that.

```
margin-top: 0px;}

h1 a { 

background-color: black;
font-size: 40px;
color: white;
margin-left: 40px;
padding: 10px 20px;
letter-spacing: -1px;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;


}


.sidenav { 

width: 150px;
position: fixed;
z-index: 1;
top: 85px;
left: 10px;
/*background: #ffffff;*/
overflow-x: hidden;
padding: 8x 0;

}

.sidenav a { 
padding: 4px 1px 4px 40px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 25px;
color: #000000;
display: block;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'sans-serif';    

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the image the background of the body or a div (is how I would do it).

CSS:

```css
body {
    background: url("");
}
```

or

```css
.coolbackground {
    background: url("");
}
```

---

You can set how it covers the page using:

```css
    background-size: ;
```

and

```css
    background-repeat: ;
```

---

Else if you dont want to do that, use a float, absolute positioning and z-index.